# Read column from Datastore Amplify using react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am writing a react app using AWS amplify datastore library, I want to read a whole column and put it in the drop-down select menu. I have completed designing the UI but I don't how to get only one column rather than having the whole table
Currently my query statement looks something like this
`await Datastore.query(myTable);`
This returns the whole table. I want to know if I can get myTable.id where 'id' is column name

Comment: Do you need to query for a specific column for perfomance reasons? because if that's not the case you could iterate over the response and retrieve the `ids` with an `.map`.

Comment: Thank you @samuelsilva for replying, I was able to retrieve the specific column using .map, but I want to is there any way I can just pull data of single column rather that getting the whole table and then use map to get the required data, To answer your question, yes I need a query for specific column for performance reasons

Comment: also another option, could you do something like is suggested in this issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5155

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Amplify Datastore is already maintaining a local replica of your data, the recommendation from Samuel above is reasonable. Writing something like `const ids = await Datastore.query(myTable).map(record => record.id)` to get the `id` fields for all records in your table should work, and unless your data is really massive (in which case I'd imagine you're not trying to do that to fill a dropdown in UI) this should be reasonably fast.

The other alternative would be to query using the `API` category https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/ with a custom graphql doc that included only `id` in the selection set, but that's not really recommended, since you're going to need to hit your backend API unnecessarily in that case, rather than relying on the local data which Datastore maintains.